# When double clicking word document it will not launch

Tags: microsoft-word

Microsoft Word will not launch. ... Whether I use the Start Menu or Desktop Icon. 
I double clicked on document and it takes at least 1 minute to open word and I get a blank screen. I then have to go to file open and find it to open it.

Comment: Whats your OS? Have you tried re-installing MS Office? I recall having a similar problem and a re-install took care of it

Answer (score 5):

Insert the Office CD, when the installation screen comes up, choose the repair option. This will repair any corruption that might have occured due to a virus or any misconfiguration that could've happened over time.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the normal.dot (and the temp normal.dot which is in the same folder and begins with a ~)

From: http://www.marshalladulteducation.org/techtips/techtip72.htm

1. Double click on My Computer.
2. Click on the Tools menu in the top menu bar.
3. Click on Folder Options...
4. Click on the View Tab
5. Click on the little button next to "Show hidden files and folders" (in the Advanced Settings box)
6. Click OK.
7. Double click on Local Disk (C:)
8. Double click on the Documents and Settings folder
9. Double click on the folder with your user name
10. Double click on Application Data. (That folder will be dimmed)
11. Double click on the Microsoft folder.
12. Double click on the Templates folder.
13. Right click on the Normal.dot file and delete it
14. Now you need to hide your hidden folders again
15. Click on the Tools menu in the top menu bar.
16. Click on Folder Options...
17. Click on the View tab.
18. Click on the little button next to "Do not show hidden files and folders" (in the Advanced Settings box)
19. Click on OK.
20. Close all the open windows and you are done

Comment: Didn't fix it for my user.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this problem and here's my solution:

1. Open Explorer.
2. Click Tools > Folder Options...
3. Click the File Types tab.
4. Scroll down to the file extension of the affected program (in this case, doc).
5. Select the desired file extension and click the Advanced button.  This will open the Edit File Type dialog box.
6. Select the Open option, then click Edit...
7. Find the line "Application used to perform action". Scroll to the end of the path (for example, my computer lists C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\WINWORD.EXE" /n).
8. Look for a switch labeled /dde at the end of the path.
9. Delete /dde and type "%1" (including quotes) at the end of the path.
10. Clear the "Use DDE" option.
11. Click OK, then OK again.
12. Double-click on the desired file.  It should launch quickly.

If this works, you'll need to repeat this process for each file extension handled by Word.  It's a pain in the neck, but it fixed my problem.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds bizarre but I was also unable to open a Word doc. in Word 2003 under Windows 11 by double-clicking on it. Trying various things almost at random I discovered that unclicking "Run this program as an administrator" resolved the issue! Go to the Word icon on desktop or taskbar / right-click / open Properties > Compatibility and unclick "Run this program as an administrator". Probably the same in Windows 10.